# Symfony 2.5 Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml

I have this error when I try to proceed with Symfony 2.5:

**Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: MySpace\WelcomeBundle\Controller\HomepageController vs MySpace\WelcomeBundle\Controller\HomePageController**

Here's my code in **app/config/routing.yml**

`MySpaceWelcomeBundle:
    resource: "@MySpaceBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /`

Here's my code in my ***bundle MySpace*, in src/MySpace/WelcomeBundle/Controller/HomePageController.php**:

```
<?php

namespace MySpace\WelcomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HomePageController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MySpaceWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

and finally this is my code in **src/MySpace/WelcomeBundle/Ressources/config/routing.yml**

```
MySpaceWelcomeBundle_HomePage:
pattern:  /
defaults: { _controller: MySpaceWelcomeBundle:Homepage:index }
```

Someone could explain me exactly what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is with `src/MySpace/WelcomeBundle/Ressources/config/routing.yml`, as you have `Homepage` with lowecase. Try to change it to:

```
MySpaceWelcomeBundle_HomePage:
pattern:  /
defaults: { _controller: MySpaceWelcomeBundle:HomePage:index }
```

Comment: thank you, you're right, this is a rookie mistake. I forgot like you told the Uppercase of HomePage.

Comment: For a rookie, pointing out that HomePage in the routing file is the HomePageController, was the key. Although obvious now it's fixed I was looking for that exact lowercase example instead of realising these two were related